# Google Mail API

Tags: gmail, google-api

I have a google mail API and the users are logging in now by 
going to a url like say: mail.xxxxx.edu.in. but i don't want my 
users to  go to the login page provided by google (here: 
mail.xxxxx.edu.in). Instead I want users to login directly to their 
mailbox by entering details in the custom login control i have created 
in my home page and then use google interface for email operations.

Can you please tell me if this is possible and if so, how.

Comment: Is it me or does this sound against the Terms Of Service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, and [here](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/sso/saml_reference_implementation.html) is the information you'll need on how to do it.

Comment: cool. Can you explain bit more, please. How can I do login process using PHP and on which page, users will be redirected ? Is that possible with javascript ?

Comment: Not quite that simple unfortunately. You need to set up and configure a SAML-compliant ID Provider, configure it to talk to Google, and configure it how to authenticate your users. http://simplesamlphp.org/docs/1.5/simplesamlphp-googleapps has a great walkthrough of the steps required.